# (1054, "Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'")

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

the date field is there in both models and datasbase, but still it showing error as "(1054, "Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'")" I dnt know where the mistake is

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import feed

class feed_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = feed
        fields = ('feed_text',  )
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    form = feed_form(data=request.POST)
    feed_cont = form.save(commit=False)
    feed_cont.user = User.objects.get(pk =1)
    feed_cont.upvote = 0
    feed_cont.downvote = 0
    feed_cont.date = "hello"
    feed_cont.save()
    return render(request,'feeds/feeds.html')
```

models.py

```
class feed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True)
    feed_text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    upvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return feed.content
```

why this error is coming ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yoy have the `date` column in you model, but you do not have such column in the table stored in the database. You should create that column (manually or using [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/)), because `syncdb` won't create it.

Comment: But the OP clearly states that `the date field is there in both models and datasbase`.

Comment: yeah right .. As i stated that date field is in both models and database. and it still displays like that. can anyone help to solve this ?